# Sync scrollview paging with onAppear

Tags: swiftui

I am testing the new scrollview animation in SwiftUI.  I have enabled paging in the code below.  I have used onAppear and when the app is first launched, it prints out "samsung" and "apple".  When I make a scroll, it prints out "google".

How can I make the onAppear to sync with the actual page in scrollview.  So when the text is showing "apple", the onAppear will only print out "apple".

```
import SwiftUI

struct CardItem: Identifiable {
   var id: Int
   var name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
   
   let cards = [CardItem(id: 1, name: "Apple"), CardItem(id: 2, name: "Samsung"), CardItem(id: 3, name:"Google")]
   
   var body: some View {
      ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
         LazyVStack {
            ForEach(cards) { card in
               ZStack {
                  Text(card.name)
                     .zIndex(3)
                  RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                     .fill(.ultraThinMaterial)
                     .containerRelativeFrame(.vertical)
                     .scrollTransition(axis: .vertical) { content, phase in
                        content.scaleEffect(x: phase.isIdentity ? 1.0 : 0.8, y: phase.isIdentity ? 1.0 : 0.8)
                     }
                     .zIndex(2)
               }
               .onAppear {
                  print(card.name)
               }
            }
        
         }
         
      }
      .scrollTargetLayout()
      .contentMargins(20)
      .background(LinearGradient(colors: [.purple, .blue], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
      .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
   }
}

#Preview {
   ContentView()
}
```

Comment: This soundsl ike an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Are you just trying to detect when the page changes, and get the card for the current page?

Comment: No, I wanted to play a sound related to card name when it appears.

Comment: That confirms my guess - so you just need to detect when the page changes, and get the name of the card for the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to track the scroll position with `.scrollPosition`, and detect a change in the scroll position with `.onChange`. This means that you should use the `.viewAligned` scroll target behaviour. Since each view fills up the scroll view anyway, this is not that different from `.paging`.

```
let cards = [CardItem(id: 1, name: "Apple"), CardItem(id: 2, name: "Samsung"), CardItem(id: 3, name:"Google")]

@State var scrollPosition: Int? = 1

var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(cards) { card in
                ZStack {
                    Text(card.name)
                        .zIndex(3)
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                        .fill(.ultraThinMaterial)
                        .containerRelativeFrame(.vertical)
                        .scrollTransition(axis: .vertical) { content, phase in
                            content.scaleEffect(x: phase.isIdentity ? 1.0 : 0.8, y: phase.isIdentity ? 1.0 : 0.8)
                        }
                        .zIndex(2)
                }
            }
            
        }
        .scrollTargetLayout()
    }
    .contentMargins(20)
    .background(LinearGradient(colors: [.purple, .blue], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
    .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned(limitBehavior: .always))
    .scrollPosition(id: $scrollPosition)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .onChange(of: scrollPosition, initial: true) { oldValue, newValue in
        if let card = cards.first(where: { $0.id == newValue }) {
            print(card.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the type of `scrollPosition` should be the same as the type used for `CardItem`'s `id`, wrapped in an `Optional`. `ForEach(cards)` assigns the `id` of each card to each of the views it creates.

If the names of the cards are unique, it could be more convenient to use their names as `id` instead:

```
@State var scrollPosition: String? = "Apple"

... 

ForEach(cards, id: \.name) { ... }

...

// To print the card's name, you can simply print scrollPosition
.onChange(of: scrollPosition, initial: true) { oldValue, newValue in
    if let newValue {
        print(newValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried your code, when I scroll up, "Samsung" is somehow not printed.  Since it is paginated and so for each scroll, need to some how play a sound in onAppear related to the name of the card.

Comment: @DarylWong Oops, forgot to change to `.viewAligned` behaviour, now fixed. You should really stop thinking about `onAppear`. It is not reliable for such purposes.